# Pause on Lock for Spotify?

Tags: lock-screen, 20.04, music, spotify

Does anyone knows how to get "Pause on Lock" to work for Ubuntu 20.04 ? Terminal says, "sudo install pause-on-lock /usr/local/bin/"

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/08/ubuntu-pause-music-screen-lock-kicks-resume-unlocked

Comment: Did you try playerctl as suggested by the article's author in the comments 3 years ago?

Comment: Playerctl is not in Ubuntu store nor at Snapcraft either.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What exactly did you try doing and what went not as expected? The answer to your current question is included in the link you have provided.

Comment: may I get lock screen mini player as this for Ubuntu 20.;04 with Spotify and/or YouTube Music ?

https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-uniblog-publish-prod/original_images/LockScreenMedia_FinalGIF.gif

Comment: @ChristianBearslyClark: `sudo apt install playerctl` worked just fine for me on `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS` so  playerctl  is available for ubuntu :)